# Issue with wiring eMylo remote control switch

Tags: remote-control

My eMylo switch has five electric sockets (which can be wired.)

The wiring diagram shows that the input positive (anode - the red wire from the 12 DC power) must be wired to the most right socket of the switch, the input negative (cathode - the black wire from the 12 DC power) must be wired to the second-right socket of the switch.

The wiring diagram shows, that the output positive is just the input positive (split before it enters the most right socket of the eMylo switch,) and the output negative is the third-right socket of the switch. The diagram also shows that there is a red wire inside the eMylo switch, which connects the second-right socket (the one connected to the input negative) with the fourth-right socket of the switch (I have no clue for what reason.)

When I wire the switch to the input positive (anode) and negative (cathode), the switch's light goes on. When I press the transmitter's button, another light goes on (indicating, that the switch is receiving the signal from the transmitter). HOWEVER, the voltage between the input positive and the third-right socket stays 0 (while it should become 12V at this point) - the switch does not do its job.

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone, please, guide me?

[image]

[image]node)

[image]

Comment: A link to the user manual, a picture and a diagram would be so much better than all those words. You can add a schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. I don't think "anode and cathode" are the right words to be using so I suspect that English is not your first language. If you add some country / language info into your user profile we may be able to understand your terminology.

Comment: Please provide a link to a datasheet or instruction manual for the specific device you have.  If nothing else, a photo or sketch of your switch would help us help you.

Comment: @Transistor thank you for your reply. I added a photo of the wiring diagram and of my device.

Comment: @PeterBennett thank you for your reply. I added a photo of the wiring diagram and of my device.

Comment: Can you show a larger, less fuzzy, picture of Diagram 1, please.  We don't use "Anode" and "Cathode" the way they do in their instructions.  I would probably say "Positive" rather than "Anode", and "Ground" or "Negative" than "Cathode".

Comment: Thank you @PeterBennett. I took another picture (still not perfect, but better than before).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you DO need to add the connection between terminals 2 and 4, as shown by the red line in Diagram 1.  The relay will make a connection between terminals 3 and 4 when it is "on".

Comment: Thank you Peter Bennet. Now, that you explained this, it does make sense. What this eMylo switch probably does, is: When the signal is received, the switch lets the current flow from terminal 3 (where I placed the yellow wire) to terminal 4 (which their diagram says to connect to the black wire). By "current flows" I mean from positive to negative. If this is so, I can use pair terminal 3 - terminal 4 as a on/off switch for another circuit. On Sunday, I will check if your idea of wiring terminal 2 to terminal 4 works (it should), and write about the outcome here. Thank you!

Comment: disclaimer: I haven't seen or used any eMylo devices - my comments are just an educated guess, based on the illustrations in the instruction sheet, and a knowledge of how things are likely to be wired..

Comment: I tested your wiring suggestion today and IT WORKED!

Thank you!

P.S. Now, I am using that eMylo switch as a break for another circuit, which I connect to the third and the forth sockets of the eMylo switch (of course, I am careful about the polarity of that other circuit). And it works too. Again, thank you Peter Bennett !!